# How can I change hover color like in the screenshot shown?

Tags: angular

How can I change the hover color?

[image]

I need to change hover style dynamically. How can I do that like in [this link](http://bootstrapdesigntools.com/tools/bootstrap-menu-builder/) ?

```html
<style>
  #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
  {
    background-color: {{mycolor}};
  }
</style>
<div class="col-6">
  Background color
  <input class="form-control" [value]="mycolor"
    [style.background]="mycolor" [(colorPicker)]="mycolor" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp There is a html5 component for this.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend:-
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/colorpicker

1) Use Primeng- colorPicker

```
<p-colorPicker [(ngModel)]="color"></p-colorPicker>
```

Using Primeng in angular:-
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup